# Why are Vue.js builds so huge?

Tags: vue.js

I use Vue.js + vue-cli + webpack to create SPA's. The build sizes it produces are staggeringly large compared to the source I create. I recognize that a whole lot of library code is pulled in, but is there any way to optimize it further. As an example, my 200KB of templates and JavaScript, produces 2.1MB in JavaScript code alone! Is there anything that can be done to optimize this?

Comment: I can't imagine the built files (what ends up in the dist directory) are 21 megabytes. I just built the webpack template without any code modifications and its 1MB and 80% of that is the map file.

Comment: My bad. I missed a period. 2.1MB.